# Django - Annotating an aggregation of annotations on related objects

Tags: python, django

I have three models:

```py
class BaseModel(Model):
    deleted = BooleanField(default=False)


class Document(BaseModel):
    def total_price()
        return DocumentLine.objects.filter(
            section__in=self.sections.filter(deleted=False),
            deleted=False,
        ).total_price()


class Section(BaseModel):
    document = ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='sections')


class LineQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def with_total_price(self):
        total_price = F('quantity') * F('price')
        return self.annotate(
            total_price=ExpressionWrapper(total_price, output_field=DecimalField())
        )
    
    def total_price(self):
        return self.with_total_prices().aggregate(
            Sum('total_price', output_field=DecimalField())
        )['total_price__sum'] or Decimal(0.0)


class Line(BaseModel):
    objects = LineQuerySet.as_manager()
    section = ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='lines')

    price = DecimalField()
    quantity = DecimalField()
```

As you can see on the `LineQuerySet`, there is a method that will annotate the queryset with the total price of each line, based on the price and quantity.

Now I can easily get the total price of an entire document doing something like this (Note that lines and sections with `deleted=True` are ignored):

```
document = Document.objects.get(pk=1)
total_price = document.total_price()
```

However, now I would like to generate a queryset of multiple documents, and annotate that with each document's `total price`. I've tried a combination of annotates, aggregates, making use of prefetch_related (using Prefetch), and OuterRef, but I can't quite seem to be able to get the result I want without it throwing an error.

Is there some way to perform this operation in a queryset, making it then possible to filter or order by this `total_price` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Document.objects.filter(
    deleted=False,
    sections__deleted=False,
    section__lines__deleted=False
).annotate(
    total_price=Sum(F('sections__lines__price')*F('sections__lines__quantity'))
)
```

Each `Document` that arises from this queryset will have an attribute `.total_price` which is the sum of the price times the quantity of all *related* lines of all *related* sections of that `Document`.

An alternative is to work with a [**`Subquery`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to determine the sum, so:

```
from django.db.models import F, OuterRef, Subquery, Sum

Document.objects.annotate(
    total_price=Subquery(
        Line.objects.values(
            document_id=F('section__document_id')
        ).filter(
            deleted=False, section__deleted=False, document__deleted=False
        ).annotate(
            total_price=Sum(F('price') * F('quantity'))
        ).order_by('document_id').filter(document_id=OuterRef('pk')).values('total_price')[:1]
    )
)
```

Comment: That gets me closer to the result I want, but it looks like I've left out some crucial information. I've updated the post. Each model also has a `deleted` flag, which when `True` means it should be ignored from the total_price. If a linegroup is deleted, all related lines should also be ignored, whether they're deleted or not.

Comment: That's *almost* there. The only problem now is that a document with a single section that is deleted will not be included in the queryset, because the filter is not satisfied for that document. Same with a document that has a section, but no lines in that section.

Comment: I finally got it to work using your last edit. I did need to add another `.values('total_price')` to filter out the document_id, to prevent an error of multiple columns returned.
One thing I don't quite understand is the Sum annotation on the Line queryset. Does this add the result of the sum to every row in the Line result query? After which you just select the first one?

Comment: @Swan: we make a `GROUP BY` on the `document_id` in the subquery, and thus it will determine the sum of that group through `.annotate(..)`.